# Capturing Esc Key with jQuery on Document, but Not Contents

Tags: jquery, keydown, event-bubbling, esc-key

Imagine an HTML form and the jQuery library is loaded. I'd like it such that if someone is not currently focused on a form field, and they click the Esc key, a dialog pops up to ask if they want to close the form window (because the form window opened as a new tab).

If I try to capture it on $(document), the trouble I have is with event bubbling where the fields pick this up, so an Esc key press in a field causes the event to fire.

How can I efficiently (key word) prevent the event bubble and capture when Esc is pressed when no fields have the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use an If statement to check that none of the inputs have focus:

`if ($('input').is(":focus")){ ... }`

In [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/vEB73/) i use the enter key press to check for focus.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is this applicable to all browsers ? say IE6 or 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    var cancelClose=false; // This is a global variable

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input, textarea,select').each(
                function(){
                    $(this).focus(
                            function(){
                                cancelClose=true;
                            }
                        );
                    $(this).blur(
                            function(){
                                cancelClose=false;
                            }
                        );
                }
        );
    });
```

and then, on document key down event

say :

```
  if (cancelClose)
         return false;
```

Comment: You dont need to specify each input explicitly. This can cause problems. You can just use $(input).

Comment: @AlexThomas thanx, u r right  I edited it :)
I added "select" also